# My embed code doesn't work on some sites (Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Tags: wordpress, embedded-resource, connection-refused

I am using the following `embed` `code` below an infographic on my site (to allow people to easily share the image):

```html
<a href="http://gunsafeslab.com/8-crucial-steps-survive-mass-shooting/"><img src="http://gunsafeslab.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/The-8-Crucial-Steps-to-Follow-to-Survive-a-Mass-Shooting.jpg" alt="The 8 Crucial Steps to Follow to Survive a Mass Shooting" width="700px" border="0" /></a>
```

I have got 15 `embeds` to that image till now and I see that 4 of the sites which are using the `code` aren't able to show the image on their sites. It just appears broken.

At first, I thought that it might be the issue of `hotlink` protection, but that should mean that the `embed` code shouldn't work on all the 15 sites and the infographic shouldn't load on all.

I had a look at the console of those particular sites and I found this error codes marked near my embed code:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I did my homework and tried searching online for a solution but the responses were not exactly helping me. I request you guys to help me with this and I really appreciate your time and effort.

I am using Google Chrome, if that matters.

Regards.

Comment: Your site SSL enabled?

Comment: I think external URL not allowed for your site can you check?

Answer (score 0):

Working on SSL.

```
<iframe width="250" height="260" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"src="/redirect.php?url=https://dns/files.aspx" scrolling="auto">[Your browser does not support frames or is currently configured not to display frames. Please use an up-to-date browser that is capable of displaying frames.]</iframe>enter code here
```

redirect.php

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('https://dns/files.aspx');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while embedding a website in another website (Squarespace) The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a , , or . Sites can use this to avoid click-jacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites. There are three possible directives for X-Frame-Options:

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://toucan-springtail-bftp.squarespace.com/
```

I used the 3'd option and the URL after ALLOW-FROM is the URL of the website where you want to embed.

And it worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind guys. I found the solution. It's because those websites had SSL and were requesting the infographic on my site using https and that's what caused the error. I will move my site to SSL and that should fix the issue.